# Finding nearby points using dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to find the nearest points in a dictionary to every other point. In this dict, the keys are point coordinates, which look like this

```
print d1
{(1, 1): 0, (2, 1): 1, (3, 1): 2, (10, 41):3}
```

The output here should be another dictionary with the keys as each position and the values being a list of nearby points. A nearby point is defined as being `+/- 1` away from any other point (if there are no nearby points, then something like "nan" can be set as a value).

For example, the output here should look like this:

```
{(1, 1): [(2,1)], (2, 1): [(1,1), (3,1)], (3, 1): [(2,1)], (10, 41): nan}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to iterate over the keys and values of the original dictionary and search for similar keys in the dictionary. Lasting, simple filtering will create `"nan"` if no result is found for any key:

```
d = {(1, 1): 0, (2, 1): 1, (3, 1): 2, (10, 41):3}
new_d = {a:[c for c, b in d.items() if any(abs(i-a[0]) == 1 or abs(i-a[-1])==1 for i in c) and c != a] for a, h in d.items()}
final_d = {a:"nan" if not b else b for a, b in new_d.items()}
```

Alternative solution with `math.hypot()`:

```
import math
new_d = {a:[c for c, b in d.items() if math.hypot(a[0]-c[0], a[1]-c[1])<= 1 and c != a] for a, h in d.items()}
final_d = {a:"nan" if not b else b for a, b in new_d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{(3, 1): [(2, 1)], (10, 41): 'nan', (1, 1): [(2, 1)], (2, 1): [(3, 1), (1, 1)]}
```

Comment: Can't seem to get your output. Result I get is the following: 

`{(1, 1): [(3, 1), (10, 41), (2, 1)],
 (2, 1): [(3, 1), (10, 41), (1, 1)],
 (3, 1): [(10, 41), (1, 1), (2, 1)],
 (10, 41): [(3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)]}`

Comment: Aside from you answering a very poor question, your answer doesn't make sense. If the keys are point coordinates, seems like one would need to use something like [`math.hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) to determine the Euclidean distances between them (which would necessary for determining "nearness").

Comment: @user3067923 that is odd, I did not receive `{(1, 1): [(3, 1), (10, 41), (2, 1)], (2, 1): [(3, 1), (10, 41), (1, 1)], (3, 1): [(10, 41), (1, 1), (2, 1)], (10, 41): [(3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)]}` when I ran this code. Did you run exactly the code posted above?

Comment: @martineau good idea regarding `math.hypot`. I overlooked the notion of Euclidean distance in the OP's post. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Somewhat of an improvement, however the math is wrong. You need to pass it the difference in x values and y values of each pair of points. I.E. the distance between points `p1` and `p2` would be `hypot(p2[0]-p1[0], p2[1]-p1[1])`. You  also don't need all those `abs()` calls because the distances returned will always be non-negative values due to the `sqrt()` involved (within `math.hypot()`.

Comment: Math looks right now. Also note that the way to write a floating point `NaN` value in Python is either as `float('nan')` or `math.nan`—see the `math` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.nan) on the subject. It's unclear what the OP actually wants, though.

Comment: Take the following `dict` for example: `d = { (3,11):0, (13,2):1, (12,3):2, (14,6):3, (13,1):4, (143,2):5, (10,7):6 }` The answer here should be `NaN` for `(10,7)` but it is not using @Ajax1234 's answer